# jQuery bug: replaceWIth/html mangles my DOM (all tags go out of form tag)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'v got the table, and I need to change something in it.
I want to do this by ajax: user clicks on "change" button, some field convert to editables, and then user can save it.
The code is pretty easy:

```
$(".edit_button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var trContainer = $(this).closest('tr');
    trContainer.replaceWith(content);
});
```

In original code I download a page via $.GET, then store it in 'content' variable.
Structure is (simplified):

```
<tr>
<form>
<td></td> // -- note, <td> are inside of <form>
<td></td>
</form>
</tr>
```

So, I expect that table line will change.
And it's changing!... But the problem is, that DOM of loaded element is mangled. Everything threw out of form tag. I use Google Chrome console to watch the DOM, and I see that replaced DOM looks like (simplifed)

```
<tr>
<form></form> // -- here, why <form> is empty?
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

So, my input tags are not wrapped in form.

I build minimalistic example, check it out. Click on 'change', then watch the DOM and compare it to a content string.

http://jsfiddle.net/Es8fQ/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are appending invalid HTML.

TD elements can only be inside tables, and can't be direct children of form elements, so the browser autocloses the form tags to try and fix the errors you've made.

The solution is to make sure your HTML is valid before you append it.

Comment: Addition: you can use Firebug (or your browser's equivalent tool) to inspect what HTML looks like after it's been fixed by the browser. That's the actual HTML code as seen by JavaScript.